# Method as does not exist and Artisan command not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am having a weird problem after removing a package.

> composer remove barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

It gives me this error:

[image: Removing Laravel Debugger Error]
After that, I can't use the artisan command anymore.

[image: Artisan command not found]

PHP just can't find the artisan command! I've tried with installing packages again

> composer install

Here is the Macroable.php file

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
    {
        if (! static::hasMacro($method)) {
            throw new BadMethodCallException("Method {$method} does not exist.");
        }

        $macro = static::$macros[$method];

        if ($macro instanceof Closure) {
            return call_user_func_array($macro->bindTo($this, static::class), $parameters);
        }

        return call_user_func_array($macro, $parameters);
    }
```

It gives this error[image: Composer Install Error]
Prograbbly composer tries to execute "php artisan package:discover" where composer can't find the Artisan command. If anybody faced similar problem please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that one of the service providers, either your own or one of the packages you've installed is making reference to the method `as` in the `Macroable` trait.

Try running `php artisan package:discover --vvv`. That will give you a stack trace and you can find the offending code.

Comment: I can't run the php artisan command. It always has the same error.

Comment: Yes, the `--vvv` tells it to be more verbose. It'll give you more information. Or check the `storage/logs/laravel.log` for the error stacktrace.

Comment: I was tried to remove a package named " barryvdh/laravel-debugbar", It return an error with `In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

  Class 'Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider' not found`


After that, This error is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know What I've done but this problem fixed by removing a duplicate route!

Comment: What were the routes?